# Whitelist IPs of Cloud Front on the firewall

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudfront

I want to whitelist the IPs of AWS Cloud Front on the firewall to communicate with some services on internal network. Do I've to allow the whole IPs of AWS Region "Global" where the Cloud Front Service resides or should I whitelist all IPs of AWS?

Answer (score 1):

You can get the Locations and IP Address Ranges of CloudFront Edge Servers from [this](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/LocationsOfEdgeServers.html) link.

However, these IPs are getting changed once in a while. Therefore it is important to be aware of these changes. This could be done by listening to a [SNS topic](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/subscribe-to-aws-public-ip-address-changes-via-amazon-sns/).